# Appropriate language to write a Script that Kills Long running query MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scripting, python, mongodb-3.6

I want to create a script that kills queries when they reach  specific time threshold, I will be using [db.currentOp()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) method to get information about currently running queries, and use [db.killOp](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) to kill the query, My organization mostly uses shell scripts but I find them confusing and not good enough to handle exceptions and errors, Is shell script good enough to get this done? or should I be using python which I am much more comfortable with

MongoDB 3.6.13

Comment: Is there no "query timeout" property on whatever you use to send SQL queries to the database?

Comment: there is nothing like that on the client side, but I have discovered that there is cursor.maxTimeMS() function in MongoDB which can be set to kill queries when it crossed specified threshold, but it requires to be set for each type of query, 
I need something that when run can kill every long running query @PhillW.